# Jump with an html anchor

Tags: html, css, anchor

Have a site on WordPress with Avada Fusion theme.

Created a Title element and added the following:

```
<h1 id="curriculum">Curriculum</h1>
```

In another place I create a text element that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/course-wpf/#curriculum" target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer">View Curriculum</a>
```

When I click on the link I get right BELOW the header. How to jump right BEFORE the header?

Comment: you could do it with javascript, offset it with 50px or something.

Comment: @ShenYudong — Define "this"? Are you suggesting that using a relative URI instead of an absolute URI would solve a problem? Why would it?

Comment: ist there something that overlaps the headline? Like a sticky header or something? Because it should normally jump before the headline, like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/a2jqk6k6/

Comment: @quentin, you right, i think url is not the matter too.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/course-wpf/PAGENAME#curriculum" target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer">View Curriculum</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/course-wpf#curriculum" target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer">View Curriculum</a>
```

Comment: Why should that make a difference?

Comment: @Quentin and it doesn't

Comment: the /  in end of url